# how to create a class that extends a class using javassist?

Tags: java, javassist

Hello everone i just want to know how can one create a class dynamically which extends another class using javassist library ? for 
eg superclass ResourceConfig and now i want to create a class that extends ResourceConfig using javassist.

Comment: have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31050473/javassist-creating-an-interface-that-extends-another-interface-with-generics